How to use the "\textattachfile" with spaces in their path?
How to use the "\textattachfile"  with spaces in their path?
i used attachfile2 to put something into PDF document，When there are spaces in the file name, it Unable to compile.
I tried many ways(For example, add double quotes or something like that) but none worked.
(My compilation routine is  Lualatex)
i need to fix it:
\textattachfile{file name.pdf}{wow}
How to use the "\textattachfile"  with spaces in their path?  help PLZ


When I use Xelatex it works fine. But when I use LuaLatex, I get an error. Because I need to use emoji. So I have to use lualatex. (and need to compile Chinese).
This is the log file: (pasted below)
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4) (format=luahblatex 2024.7.10)  14 JUL 2024 22:01
 restricted system commands enabled.
**E:/Downloads/新建文件夹/test.tex
(E:/Downloads/新建文件夹/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/81076/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "D:/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/81076/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/ba
se/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/81076/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count192
\c@section=\count193
\c@subsection=\count194
\c@subsubsection=\count195
\c@paragraph=\count196
\c@subparagraph=\count197
\c@figure=\count198
\c@table=\count199
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/attachfile2/attachfile2.sty
Package: attachfile2 2024-01-18 v2.12 Attach files into PDF (HO)

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2024/01/14 v1.3d Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 149.

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2e Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
))
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks18
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-05-23 v7.01i Hypertext links for LaTeX

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count266
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count267
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen141
\Hy@linkcounter=\count268
\Hy@pagecounter=\count269

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-05-23 v7.01i Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count270

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-05-23 v7.01i Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4157.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4162.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4165.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4172.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4177.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4424.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count271
 (D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4763.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen142

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count272
\Field@Width=\dimen143
\Fld@charsize=\dimen144
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6042.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6047.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6050.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6057.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6062.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6067.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6072.

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count273
\c@Item=\count274
\c@Hfootnote=\count275
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hluatex.

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
File: hluatex.def 2024-05-23 v7.01i Hyperref driver for luaTeX

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count276
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count277

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip51
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/attachfile2/atfi-luatex.def
File: atfi-luatex.def 2024-01-18 v2.12 attachfile2 driver for luaTeX (HO)
)
\atfi@stream=\write3

\openout3 = test.atfi
\atfi@appearancewidth=\skip52
\atfi@appearanceheight=\skip53
\atfi@appearancedepth=\skip54
\atfi@appearancebox=\box52
\c@atfi@flags=\count278
)
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count279
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
)
No file test.aux.

\openout1 = test.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(D:/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count280
\scratchdimen=\dimen145
\scratchbox=\box54
\nofMPsegments=\count281
\nofMParguments=\count282
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count283
\MPscratchDim=\dimen146
\MPnumerator=\count284
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count285
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
)
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 5.
\@outlinefile=\write4

\openout4 = test.out

! error:  (pdf backend): cannot open file for embedding
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Now, I succeeded! I did nothing but delete the file name of the pdf and rename it with the same name, and then used LuaLaTex and it ran successfully!
I do not know why！
thank you so much for your help!  @David Carlisle @Ulrike Fischer

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Rename the file to avoid the spaces always work.

@Fran Thank you for your reply. but I wanted to keep the space.

I put an example in my answer, if that does not work for you show your full log so we can see the error messages  just saying "Unable to compile." does not give anyone any information to debug your problem.

Good that the issue is resolved, although it is unclear why - let's close it as "not reproducible".

You showed no code, but using texlive 2024 lualatex this works for me
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile2}

\begin{document}

aaa

\textattachfile{file name.pdf}{wow}

bbb

\end{document}

The terminal shows the file being included
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/attachfile2/atfi-luatex.def))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
No file aa676.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)<<file name.pdf>>{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pd
ftex.map}
[1] 

and the pdf viewer shows file name.pdf in the attachments list:


Thank you for your help, When I use Xelatex it works fine. But when I use LuaLatex, I get an error. Because I need to use emoji. So I have to use lualatex. (and need to compile Chinese). I posted the screenshot downstairs（At the same time, I also re-edited my question and added pictures）, please help me take a look.

@テンテン  oh it may be an issue with the miktex implementation, I'll see if any miktex users can reproduce.

@テンテン The example compiles without any problems on my miktex with lualatex. Show your complete log-file.

@David Carlisle  Thanks :)    I re-edited the question and pasted the log file. Please help me see if this can troubleshoot the problem.

@Ulrike Fischer  Thanks :) I re-edited the question and pasted the log file. Please help me see if this can troubleshoot the problem.

@David Carlisle I'm really, really sorry. you mentioned looking at the logs. So I also checked the following logs, and I saw the sentence:"! error:  (pdf backend): cannot open file for embeddin",So I tried to modify the file name (of course still retaining the spaces), and it worked fine! I don't know where the problem came from and why it's running successfully now, I don't know. I just deleted the original filename and re-entered it with the same name (yes! still the same name)，This is so hard to explain, in short thank you so much for your continued help!

@Ulrike Fischer  I'm really, really sorry. you mentioned looking at the logs. So I also checked the following logs, and I saw the sentence:"! error: (pdf backend): cannot open file for embeddin",So I tried to modify the file name (of course still retaining the spaces), and it worked fine! I don't know where the problem came from and why it's running successfully now, I don't know. I just deleted the original filename and re-entered it with the same name (yes! still the same name)，This is so hard to explain, in short thank you so much for your  help!
